# jquery userinterface load on page refresh

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am appending the datepickers to a div when user selects certain option from the select box. 
the datepickers include calendar images and i am using the url of that image. When I choose an option the div is correctly loaded but calendar images are not loaded. But when the data is posted to another page and I come back to this page the images are loaded and calendar works.

```
function add() {
   var option = $('#id').val();
    if(option !== 'valid'){
     $('#id').append('i have appended here the div that contains two datepickers');
}
}
```

The jquery code for datepicker is as follows:

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
  //optional settings, but i have given the url for the calendar image which doesn't loads (i think) 
  //when the div is being appended, but when the page refreshes it displays the images and datepicker workds
})
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML that is used?

Answer (score 0):

That is because `$('#datepicker1').datepicker({})` will only target elements that *exist* at the point of calling.

Since the loaded content was *not* existing at the time `datepicker()` was called, it wasn't targeted.

You need to call it again for the loaded content *after* it has been loaded, or bind an event handler to the load (the latter just does the former automatically).

**Javascript/jQuery code**

```
function add() {
    var option = $('#id').val();
    if (option !== 'valid') {
        $('#id').append('i have appended here the div that contains two datepickers');
        $('.datepickers').datepicker({/*...*/});
    }
}
```

A possible workaround for this is to include the datepickers initially, and set them to `display: none`, until the specified prerequisit is met.

```
function add() {
    var option = $('#id').val();
    if (option !== 'valid') {
        $('#id .extra-content').show();
    }
}
```